# How is this comparison/ranking algorithm called?

Tags: algorithm, comparison, ranking

I've seen some sites where they show two random items from a list, and users pick which one they prefer, and then based on the results of the user preferences, a ranking is generated for the entire data set. Does anyone know what this ranking algorithm is called and how it works?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there is only one possible algorithm that everyone uses for this.

Comment: Thanks, but can anyone at least tell me one possible algorithm that I can look at?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're referring to the [ELO rating system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system).

Comment: Thanks. ELO and Glicko were the methodologies I was reading up on. I just wanted to be sure that I was looking up the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

A simple implementation would be to always choose two random items for the comparison and give the preferred item a point. Then rank in order of decreasing points.

Answer (score 0):

The usual method for this is [collaborative filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering). For this usually the choices of all persons are compared and a similarity between persons is used to weight their choices, when recommending or rating items. That means, people who have shown similar choices to yours before, are used more to generate recommendations than those who have shown different behavior.

There are several methods for doing this inference, and which one is best or how to optimize the performance is an open research questions. Most often the simplest implementation will achieve sufficent predictions and is easy to implement. It just does a two multiplications of the preference matrix with itself transposed.